# the language area show pending status in iTune connect In-App purchase Details

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm configuring my In-App purchase in iTunes Connect and the area of language is always showing pending status. How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All language changes are reviewed by Apple. This process usually takes a few days.